# перегрузить функцию erase для класса set

Tags: c++, set, перегрузка-функций

```
multiset < int > S;

S.insert(1);
S.insert(1);
S.insert(2);
S.insert(2);
S.insert(3);
// S = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3}
    
S.erase(1);
S.erase(3);
S.erase(4);
```

после операций нужно, чтобы set содержал в себе `1, 2, 2`

есть реализованная функция

```
template <class T, class U> void erase(T& t, const U& u) {
    auto it = t.find(u);
    if (it != t.end()) t.erase(it);
}
```

в таком случае работает просто через `erase(S, x)`, но хотелось бы перегрузить операцию от самого класса, чтобы можно было писать `S.erase(x)`

```
template <class T> class set
{
    void erase(T u)
    {
        auto it = find(u);
        if (it != this.end()) erase(u);
    }
};
```

пытался сделать так, но по факту создается еще один класс с названием set и он не может выбрать какой именно я имею ввиду
`error: reference to 'set' is ambiguous`

подскажите как такое можно реализовать

Answer (score 1):

Это потому что вы объявляете в шаблоне новый класс с тем же именем. А вам нужно перегрузить только функцию. Сделайте так:

```
template <class T> 
void set::erase(T u)
{
  ....
}
```

При этом, эта функция должна быть в объявлении класса.
Если вы пытаетесь перегрузить функцию класса из библиотеки, доступа к коду которого нет (или изменять/дополнять его строго не рекомендуется), то нужно делать класс-наследник, перегружать функцию в нем и пользоваться уже объектами этого класса. И да, имя класса-наследника не может совпадать с именем класса-родителя.
При создании класса-наследника (в том числе контейнера стандартной библиотеки), нужно передавать параметры шаблона в родительский класс.

```
template<class _Key>
class MySet : public std::set<_Key>
{
   public:
    void erase(_Key u)
    {
    }
};
```

В общем случае, изменять поведение классов стандартной библиотеки - задача для профессионалов. В Вашем случае просто напишите свою функцию `erase()`, принимающую множество и элемент, который надо удалить, и пользуйтесь ей вместо встроенной без всяких перегрузок.

```
template <class T> 
void erase(std::set<T> &u, T &elem)
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: в первом случае ошибка 
`error: 'template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::set' used without template parameters`
а во втором 
`error: expected class-name before '{' token`
@DmitryK

Comment: Изменил в ответе. Нужно в вопросе указывать, что именно вы перегружать собрались.

Comment: `_Key` - зарезервированное имя.

Comment: заменить на любое другое `template<class T> class MySet : public std::set<T>`

Comment: Немного придерусь: не в шаблоне, а "рядом", иначе никакого _ambiguous_ бы не было (но была бы другая ошибка). Имя класса наследника может совпадать с именем базового класса - им достаточно быть в разных пространствах имен.

Comment: @isnullxbh С придирками согласен! :) Но боюсь автор вопроса таких слов не знает.